# How to plot subsets of geographic plots

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm attempting to plot Antarctic sea ice concentration using a Lambert plot.  My script produces a plot, but when I want to plot a certain area (not all of Antarctica), the plot goes haywire.

Here's my script:

```
addpath('D:\wass\m_map')

% m_proj('lambert','lat',[min(lat(:)) max(lat(:))],...
% 'lon',[min(lon(:)) max(lon(:))])
m_proj('lambert','lon',[0 120],'lat',[-80 -50]);

m_pcolor(lon,lat,ice_conc);
shading flat;

% Add a coastline and axis values.

m_coast('patch',[.7 .7 .7])
m_grid('box','fancy')

% Add a colorbar

colorbar
```

[image: subplot of sea ice concentration]

[image: full plot]

DATA:

lat:

```
-62.128365  -62.243603  -62.358810  -62.473976  -62.589111  -62.704208  -62.819267  -62.934296  -63.049286  -63.164238  -63.279160
-62.113903  -62.229088  -62.344234  -62.459347  -62.574425  -62.689465  -62.804466  -62.919434  -63.034367  -63.149261  -63.264122
-62.098972  -62.214100  -62.329189  -62.444244  -62.559261  -62.674244  -62.789188  -62.904095  -63.018967  -63.133801  -63.248600
-62.083576  -62.198643  -62.313675  -62.428673  -62.543629  -62.658550  -62.773434  -62.888279  -63.003086  -63.117859  -63.232594
-62.067715  -62.182720  -62.297691  -62.412628  -62.527523  -62.642380  -62.757202  -62.871983  -62.986729  -63.101437  -63.216106
-62.051388  -62.166332  -62.281242  -62.396111  -62.510944  -62.625740  -62.740494  -62.855213  -62.969891  -63.084530  -63.199135
-62.034595  -62.149479  -62.264324  -62.379128  -62.493896  -62.608624  -62.723312  -62.837963  -62.952576  -63.067146  -63.181683
-62.017342  -62.132160  -62.246937  -62.361675  -62.476376  -62.591038  -62.705658  -62.820240  -62.934780  -63.049286  -63.163750
-61.999626  -62.114376  -62.229088  -62.343758  -62.458389  -62.572979  -62.687531  -62.802040  -62.916512  -63.030945  -63.145336
-61.981445  -62.096127  -62.210770  -62.325371  -62.439930  -62.554451  -62.668930  -62.783371  -62.897770  -63.012127  -63.126442
-61.962807  -62.077419  -62.191990  -62.306519  -62.421005  -62.535454  -62.649860  -62.764225  -62.878548  -62.992832  -63.107075
```

lon:

```
7.0379410   7.0667295   7.0957541   7.1250162   7.1545200   7.1842675   7.2142620   7.2445068   7.2750049   7.3057594   7.3367739
7.2700686   7.2997870   7.3297477   7.3599544   7.3904090   7.4211159   7.4520774   7.4832969   7.5147777   7.5465226   7.5785356
7.5019569   7.5326014   7.5634961   7.5946436   7.6260471   7.6577096   7.6896348   7.7218256   7.7542858   7.7870178   7.8200259
7.7335982   7.7651658   7.7969913   7.8290763   7.8614254   7.8940411   7.9269266   7.9600859   7.9935217   8.0272379   8.0612373
7.9649854   7.9974732   8.0302258   8.0632458   8.0965376   8.1301022   8.1639452   8.1980686   8.2324772   8.2671738   8.3021612
8.1961117   8.2295170   8.2631931   8.2971449   8.3313751   8.3658857   8.4006824   8.4357672   8.4711447   8.5068178   8.5427895
8.4269686   8.4612885   8.4958858   8.5307655   8.5659304   8.6013851   8.6371317   8.6731739   8.7095165   8.7461624   8.7831154
8.6575518   8.6927814   8.7282963   8.7641010   8.8001976   8.8365908   8.8732843   8.9102812   8.9475851   8.9851999   9.0231295
8.8878517   8.9239883   8.9604177   8.9971437   9.0341692   9.0714979   9.1091337   9.1470804   9.1853418   9.2239227   9.2628250
9.1178627   9.1549034   9.1922426   9.2298861   9.2678366   9.3060970   9.3446722   9.3835649   9.4227810   9.4623222   9.5021944
9.3475780   9.3855181   9.4237652   9.4623222   9.5011930   9.5403814   9.5798922   9.6197281   9.6598930   9.7003918   9.7412281
```

ice_conc:

```
87.1799980513752    89.0399980098009    90.2999979816377    91.1299979630858    90.7499979715794    91.6499979514629    91.1699979621917    91.1799979619682    89.6499979961664    86.2899980712682    86.7199980616570
87.1999980509281    89.7599979937077    90.4399979785085    90.2799979820848    90.3399979807437    91.1999979615212    90.1599979847670    88.4699980225414    89.1099980082363    86.7199980616570    86.4899980667979
86.8699980583042    88.9499980118126    90.3699979800731    90.2999979816377    88.9999980106950    88.9399980120361    89.1399980075657    88.5199980214238    88.2399980276823    86.2299980726093    86.2799980714917
86.3299980703741    88.0099980328232    88.0599980317056    87.2799980491400    88.3499980252236    88.1699980292469    88.8699980136007    87.7999980375171    85.9699980784208    85.9699980784208    86.0299980770797
85.3499980922788    86.5599980652332    86.3699980694801    87.4099980462343    87.1399980522692    86.9499980565161    86.5099980663508    86.0199980773032    85.6299980860204    85.3199980929494    85.1499980967492
83.8599981255829    85.7199980840087    86.1799980737269    85.7899980824441    86.1099980752915    86.4599980674684    85.7799980826676    85.4599980898202    84.4199981130660    84.2099981177598    83.6599981300533
83.2699981387705    83.9299981240183    85.1999980956316    85.6399980857968    85.7799980826676    84.7999981045723    84.2599981166422    83.4699981343001    83.3599981367588    83.1799981407821    82.3999981582165
82.2099981624633    82.6799981519580    84.4099981132895    84.0999981202185    83.7199981287122    83.7799981273711    82.9999981448054    82.6099981535226    81.8799981698394    81.9599981680512    81.6699981745333
82.9399981461465    82.1599981635809    83.6599981300533    85.5099980887026    85.6899980846793    84.7699981052429    82.3699981588870    81.9499981682748    81.6099981758744    80.7599981948733    81.0299981888384
81.1899981852621    82.4899981562048    85.8299980815500    85.4799980893731    84.9399981014431    85.0699980985373    83.0799981430173    82.0899981651455    81.2599981836975    79.9599982127547    78.8099982384592
81.5299981776625    81.9499981682748    84.5999981090426    84.8699981030077    85.5799980871379    84.1099981199950    83.5099981334060    82.1499981638044    80.6599981971085    79.4499982241541    79.6899982187897
```

Comment: The sea-ice concentration map doesn't wrap around the Antarctic coastline.properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [mcve]. Specifically, please [edit] your post to contain the image you're talking about, and make a code that **we** can run. Thus, no dependencies on your computer or on variables you have not provided us with. Instead, make a smll example with random data. It will also help to make the question about code, rather than sea ice. People here will be looking to fix programming problems, not climate change. So make a general example

Comment: Hi Adriaan.  The data comes from an nc file, so I'm not sure if I can supply the variables.  Can you see the image?

Comment: I've put in 10X10 data for latitude, longitude and sea-ice concentration.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you have a link for `m_map` as well? It looks like it's not a built-in function.

Comment: I presume that doing `m_proj()` reduces the Lamber projection to the specified area, right? Does it help to also limit to extent of your data to that? Thus, use logical indexing to only grab data which would be within that limited projection, rather than plotting everything and then limiting the projection.

Comment: OK, I can try that with find, I guess, but how would I could I find the indices of the required area, say:
-75<=lat<=-55 and
0<=lon<=50?

How would I incorporate a command like:
lat_index_1 = find(lat >= -75);
lat_index_2 = find(lat <= -55)'

Comment: Exactly like you just wrote. Something like `idx = lat<75 & lat >50 & lon<100 & lon > 50;, then plot `plot(lat(idx),lon(idx),data(idx))`;

Comment: OK, I'll muck around with that and viz the resulting plot.  Thanks!